# The whole index.php?=<filename>.exe

Tags: php

I've never really understood on how to do it. I want to where where I can type my address, followed by /index.php?=<a file that is on the FTP>.exe. From there, I would be direct to a page that has a download now button and maybe something like a ad.

Anyone have any tutorials or guides that I may look at?

Comment: So you’re looking for something like a donwloads management script?

Comment: You should imagine that you are someone else who tries to 'understand' this 'question' ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he is on about simple $_GET requests >.<

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   echo file_get_contents($file);
}

?>
```

Ofcourse this is a very basic example with no security at all. Its not reccomended for you to use this in production without upping security on it.

Comment: Use readfile() instead of file_get_contents() - it's much more efficient in this sort of situation.

Comment: To further explain what ozzy means when he points out that their are security issues with this script, consider what would happen when $_GET['file'] = '/etc/passwd' or '../../../../../../etc/passwd', etc.  For these reasons, you probably want to do something like $file = '/my/downloads/dir/' . basename($_GET['file']);

Answer (score 3):

Im gonna bite ...

The PHP script ensures the file is not accessible from the outside, and only on a per-request basis with possible authentication. When you see:

```
download.php?file=sdjasdk.exe
```

The download script looks a bit like:

```
<?php
    if( $_SESSION['auth'] == TRUE){
        $file = fileopen($whatever);
        echo "mimetype crap"
        //spit out file
    }else{
        echo "not authorized bozo"
    }
?>
```

DOne.

Comment: you would probably send the "mimetype crap" in the response header with header() rather than echo